# Android Studio Emulator is not starting up for the first time?

Tags: android, android-studio, emulation

I just started learning android studio but for some reason, my emulator is not starting up. I read similar questions asked here and tried many different things and I manage to get the emulator loading console to appear for a few seconds before disappearing forever. Even though gradle build has become quite fast, the emulator still refuses to show.
I tried changing RAM, making new devices, updating path on 'program structures' installing HAXM and any other thing that seemed to work or other people but I still get this error when I run it
" Error while waiting for device: Timed out after 300seconds waiting for emulator to come online. "

I was really looking forward to learning app development for my project but this issue is hindering my progress significantly.
Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: My android studio is version 2.3.1 and I am following TheNewBoston video series.

Comment: Have a look at [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/)

Comment: how much is your RAM now?

Comment: what's your cpu?

Comment: use Genymotion instead of Android Studio Emulator. Genymotion is fast and much better than AS emulator

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is the Android emulator so slow? How can we speed up the Android emulator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/why-is-the-android-emulator-so-slow-how-can-we-speed-up-the-android-emulator)

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio Emulator is little slow sometimes or if you are not running a PC with good configurations , mostly it won't work , instead of running your app in Android Studio Emulator , you can [try these emulators](http://www.tricksuniversity.in/top-5-android-emulators-for-your.html)

or you can run it on your own device , for that please follow the link for [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html)